# Column inside Grid takes half width in react-native-base

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-native, native-base

I am using [React Native Base](https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase) for my iPad app and I am putting two `Col` components inside a `Grid` component like this:

```
<Container style={styles.container}>
  <Header style={styles.header}>
    <Body>
      <Title>Header</Title>
    </Body>
  </Header>
  <Content style={styles.mainContent}>
    <Grid>
      <Col style={styles.leftContent}>
      </Col>
      <Col style={styles.rightContent}>
      </Col>
    </Grid>
  </Content>
</Container>
```

My Stylesheet is like this:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    backgroundColor: '#ccc'
  },
  mainContent: {
    marginTop: 10,
  },
  header: {
    backgroundColor: '#fff'
  },
  leftContent: {
    width: 340,
    height: 686,
    backgroundColor: "green",
    marginLeft: 5,
  },
  rightContent: {
    width: 614,
    height: 686,
    backgroundColor: "yellow",
    marginLeft: 10,
    marginRight: 5,
  },
```

Both `Col` are taking almost equal width not the given width. How should I make these components to take given width?

Comment: have you try using flex ?

Answer (score 1):

i have an idea for that, you can using flex in your `col` style, first is setting flex parent component to `1` and then you can add flex into child component using `0.4` or `0.6` etc. this is the example code of your style

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    backgroundColor: '#ccc'
  },
  mainContent: {
    marginTop: 10,
    flex: 1 //this is for parent style
  },
  header: {
    backgroundColor: '#fff'
  },
  leftContent: {
    flex : 0.4, //this is for width col
    height: 686,
    backgroundColor: "green",
    marginLeft: 5,
  },
  rightContent: {
    flex: 0.6, //this is for width col
    height: 686,
    backgroundColor: "yellow",
    marginLeft: 10,
    marginRight: 5,
  }
});
```

Hope it can help you, thanks:)

Comment: Flex worked for me but is it fine to make flex value 0.614 or 0.34?

Comment: you can try to set like that, i think it should be work too

Answer (score 1):

Use flex so you can give your components specific size in this case. Adding the `flex: 0.5` CSS property to both your components will give them half their parents size if it has `flex: 1`set.

This way you can give them specific size ratios between 0 and 1. For example :

```
parent: {
    flex: 1,
},
childone: {
    flex: 0.35,
},
childtwo: {
    flex: 0.65,
}
```

Just chang flex child values to whatever you want and identify which component is your parent and which are the children.